# FC groups and finite quotients

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be finitely generated FC-groups such that $G\times \mathbb{Z}\cong H\times\mathbb{Z}$. Can we say that $G\cong H$? If $G$ is finitely generated FC-group and $$\mathcal{F}(G)=\mathcal{F}(H)$$ can we say that $H$ is FC-group too?

Comment: In the second part of the question, it's not clear if you are still assuming that $G\times \mathbb{Z}\cong H\times\mathbb{Z}$.  If not, then you might be interested in the following paper, where it is proved that there are residually finite groups with isomorphic profinite completions such that one is conjugacy separable and the other is not: http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0101.

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that FC groups are more usually called 'conjugacy separable' these days.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention above that the original feature of the above construction is that both groups are finitely presentable.

Comment: @Henry "conjugacy separable" means "residually finite with respect to conjugacy". FC-groups are still called FC-groups (meaning all conjugacy classes are finite). Finitely generated FC groups are simply central extensions of finite groups. That is why I said in one of my comments here that Ali Tavakoli should have included the definitions and motivation. FC-groups are not as popular now as they were in the 50-th - 80-th (they were popular in the USSR then). 

Comment: Mark and Ali - apologies, I was thinking of FAC groups.  But, Ali, Mark is right - you need to give the definition!

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your first question is no.  Take the group
$$ \langle a,b,c\ |\ [a,b]=[a,c]=b^{11}=1,b^c=b^4\rangle.$$

Consider the subgroups $G=\langle b,c\rangle$, $H=\langle b,ac^2\rangle$, $K_1=\langle a\rangle$, and $K_2=\langle a^2c^5\rangle$.  One can check that the group is both the direct product $G\times K_1$, and $H\times K_2$.  Both $K_1$ and $K_2$ are infinite cyclic.

Now $G\cong\langle u,v\ |\ u^{11}=1, u^v=u^4\rangle$, and $H\cong\langle x,y\ |\ x^{11}=1, x^y=x^5\rangle$.  These groups are not isomorphic, but both have finite-index centers, and so both are FC groups.

Comment: Good! I was wrong then (about part 1). Glad it is resolved. 

Answer (score 2):

About the second part of the question. If $G$ is trivial and $H$ is simple and infinite, they have the same finite quotients, so the answer is "no" in general. If $H$ is residually finite, then the answer should be "yes" because $G$ is a central extension of a finite group, but I do not know the reference now. The answer to the first part should also be "yes". See [Some cancellation theorems with applications to nilpotent groups by Hirshon](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjournals.cambridge.org%2Fproduction%2Faction%2FcjoGetFulltext%3Ffulltextid%3D4895992&ei=WnKAT4Ra0Ju3B_X5nK8G&usg=AFQjCNErZ2e-ti13L9DM5pN4n_bqmZcEig) (especially the last section) where a connection between the two parts of the question is established.

Comment: You beat me by 12 secs. Probably iPads are too slow. 

Comment: @Ben: I think you beat me by 12 seconds. 

Comment: The phrasing is ambiguous. It is not clear if he is still assuming GxZ and HxZ are isomorphic for the second part. I will leave my answer until clarification appears. 

Comment: By the paper I cited, if $G\times Z$ and $H\times Z$ are isomorphic, then $G$ and $H$ have the same pro-finite completions. So first part of the question is related to the second part. 

Comment: I think  Ali Tavakoli knows about this connection, that is why he formulated the two parts. Of course he should have explained it (and also the definition of FC) in the question itself. It would save some time. 

Comment: Mark, your link doesn't work for me. (This is a common problem when you link to something behind a paywall.)  Perhaps you could give a reference?

Comment: The link is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb Z$ is abelian and conjugacy is componentwise in direct products clearly G FC and $G\times\mathbb Z\cong H\times \mathbb Z$ implies H is FC. Since you didn't define $\mathcal F$ I can't answer the rest of the question.

Comment: @Ben: $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of finite quotients. 

Comment: @Ben: I think we both misunderstood the question in the same way. I have modified my answer.